# Overwriting bites in file using Hexadecimal value PYTHON

Tags: python, hex, byte, overwrite

I have a value "c" in hexadecimal representation: 0x515d6e39. It means that bites looks in the following way: 51 5D 6E 39. My task is to go to already existing file, open it and replace bites from positions (for example) 38th-41st with those above mentioned bites.

I have tried to open file in 'rb' mode. Then I used seek function to go wanted positions. Then used write function with value "c" but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me with this problem?

I attach my code:

```
import binascii


def main():
    a=963534161
    b=bytearray.fromhex(format(a, 'x'))
    b.reverse() ## I wanted to reverse my bites
    c=hex(int(binascii.hexlify(b),16))
    print c

    file=r'D:\Programs\WinKalk\winkalk.7zip' ## path to any file
    f=open(file, 'wb')
    f.seek(38) ## for example position 38th
    f.write(c)
    f.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Please show your code and the error

Comment: Code added. I am a beginner with those topics, so please be easy-going :)